# Dell U3011 + Quadro 4000: "Flashing" when using 30-bit DeepColor

Tags: displayport, opengl, nvidia-quadro, hdr

I have OpenGL code which successfully acquires and renders to a RGB10_A2 visual on a Windows 7 system, using a Quadro 4000 (current and previous drivers) connected to a Dell U3011 display via DisplayPort.

Unlike other DeepColor displays I've tried, this display/card combination appears to trigger the display to switch it's scanout signal for every viewport/graphic context I create, which results in a lot of "flashing" of the entire display during startup.

I can't find any settings in the NV control panel or Dell on-screen menus to help configure the system to be more DeepColor/30-bit desktop friendly.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and/or come up with a solution to avoid this behavior?

Comment: As an update, this still occurs if I switch to a 10-bit grayscale Dome E2 display via DVI as well (still using Quadro 4000).  ATI FirePro cards didn't exhibit this behavior, so I think this is a driver issue.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that my application was unmapping and remapping the 10 bpc (RGB10_A2) visuals during a table layout operation, which was causing the driver to toggle between 8 and 10 bit modes repeatedly.  It was easy to resolve the issue by simply creating a small 10 bpc window and keeping it mapped during the lifetime of the application.